# select 2 prefererences using checkbox and put in a single table

Tags: sql-server, model-view-controller, database-design, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have a reservation table

[image]

and a Preference table

[image]

And now  i have a dropdownlist from wich i chose a preference when i am making a reservation.what i want to do is to use checkbox when i am making reservation so that i can select more preferences.Is this posibile ?how can i save two preferences in same reservation table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to create a linking table with two columns: ReservationID and Preference_Id (possibly Preference_Quantity as well). ReservationID and Preference_Id would constitute the unique key for the table. This table would have FK constraints to the two original tables.

You'd have to remove Preference_Id and Preference_Quantity from the reservation table

Answer (score 1):

You can't if you want your tables to stay normalized.

What you would want to do is make another table called Reservation_Preferences and have it be made up of ReservationID, PreferenceID, and I guess Preference_Quantity. The 2 IDs would be your PK for the table, and each ID column would have a FK relationship to their respective parent table.  Remove the 2 Preference columns from the Reservation table, and you would have yourself a nice normalized schema.